# Ozone elimination

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science

I have a potential problem with airflow through a high voltage capacitively coupled RF discharge (in a tube) producing ozone. How can I remove ozone from the airflow? The use of liquids is not possible. Flow rate is quite low, in the mL per minute.

Comment: This sounds like it's more chemistry than physics. Did you try an activated charcoal filter? What exactly is the problem that the ozone poses for you - toxicity, nuisance, experimental noise?

Comment: The problem is everything associated with ozone pollution - from toxicity to degradation of seals. Ideally I would like a physical rather than chemical solution to the problem - preferably one that omits expensive words like "Platinum"

Answer (score 2):

This may be cheating - but ozone is generated by the interaction of the high voltage discharges and the oxygen in the air.

Why not flush the system with nitrogen - if there is no oxygen, no ozone will be produced. And a few mL per minute is not a lot of nitrogen. A 70 L bottle of nitrogen at 200 bar should expand into 14000 liter of nitrogen at STP - at 3 mL / min, 180 mL / hour that should last about 9 years...

Alternatively, as I mentioned in my comment, [you could use activated carbon](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/095696189380017L) - it's been done, and has been shown to work to some extent. The slower the air flow, the better chance the filter has.

See also http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10529990 :

> Activated carbon filters can be very effective at ozone removal, although not indefinitely because chemical reactions of ozone and carbon change the carbon. Initial efficiencies of the 1.27-cm thick flat samples varied from 4.6 to 98.3%.

Comment: I think it will have to be some kind of catalytic solution. If I find anything suitable I'll post here.

Comment: @DirkBruere apparently Nickel, Platinum. Palladium and Manganese oxide can all be used as catalysts to convert ozone back to oxygen. See for example [this paper](http://cmgm.stanford.edu/pbrown/protocols/Ozone_Prevention.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The absolute cheapest thing could be to wire a variable resistor in series to try to get the discharge voltage down: it's possible that you could reach a regime where you're only ionizing some of the gases in the air, without melting the resistor.

Since ozone's "badness" comes from being hyper-reactive you might be able to remove it chemically by putting some combustion process e.g. a candle in the tube. You might also be able to filter it out.

Comment: Maybe - I'm looking at ionized air optical emissions at reasonably low pressure. More Victorian physics with not a lot of online info...

Comment: Well normally what you'd do is to buy a tank and regulators and then continuously inject something else ($\text{Ne, He, CO}_2\text{, N}_2$). If your flow is 2 mL / minute then replacing all your air with a gas (or equivalently adding it to the gas, doubling your flow) requires $37 \text{ft}^3/\text{year}$; Praxair will sell you a filling of their K-tank ($\text{225 ft}^3$) of $\text N_2$ for under $\$10$ or $\text{CO}_2$ for about $\$11$. The tank might set you back a few hundred, but we're talking potentially multi-year service times.

Comment: Might be possible under lab conditions for testing, but the real thing (if it gets that far) has got to suck atmosphere

Comment: YAGNI. Solve the lab problem for now; the atmosphere problem can be deferred until after you have a working prototype and know the rest of the kinks.

Answer (score -1):

Check Stanford's solution, using manganese oxide as a catalyst for converting 2xO3 into 3xO2:

http://cmgm.stanford.edu/pbrown/protocols/Ozone_Prevention.pdf

You might design a much smaller device for your small volumes.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange Physics! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.